# request.form['key'] returns 2 values when parsing output to function

Tags: python, flask

So I'm working on a website that takes in some XML data sent through a javascript function to be processed by the server.

It's taking it in fine. It's just the fact that parsing in request.form['whateverKey'] through to an object method will make python throw an error saying that my input supplied 2 outputs, when the function only needs one. The first input seems to be an instance of the object I was just working with, the second though would be the post data in string form.

Interestingly though, it won't consider request.form['data'] two variables if I were to declare it straight into a variable (i.e: var = request.form['data']) - only for functions it seems.

Here's a snippet of the code.

```
@app.route("/dependencygraph", methods=["POST"])
def dependencygraph_landing_page():
    error = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        entity_collection.read_XML_data(request.form['xml'])

    return render_template("dependencygraph.html")
```

read_XML_data is also defined this way:

```
    def read_XML_data(data):
    #TODO: Figure out why it takes 2 variables instead
    print(data)
```

If it matters, entity_collection is an object. And its class is written and defined in a different .py.

Been googling around to no avail. Enlightening reasons for why would be helpful, and a solution (if needed) around this would be great. Thanks:3

Comment: Can you copy/paste full error?

Comment: @AdrianKrupa TypeError: read_XML_data() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: What is the signature of `entity_collection.read_XML_data(...)` ? Share it please. It can help if you would do the following print: `print(type(request.form['xml']))`

Comment: @HayashiEsme `read_XML_data` probably takes only one argument, which is object instance - passed implicit, usually named `self`.

Comment: @balderman I did that, the result is a string object, but if I parse request.form['xml'] into read_XML_data, and let it take in 2 variables - the first will the the object that it's parsing into, and the second is the string as expected from request.form['xml']. The other function was updated into a question

Comment: @AdrianKrupa Oh, I see. Is the self variable compulsory in Flask? I was under the impression that self wasn't compulsory in Python.

Comment: @AdrianKrupa Oh, shoot. Completely forgot that self /has/ to be declared in python. My bad. Thank you!